# Trouble with regex in javascript; any content within <angular> brackets disappear

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I am trying to parse a formula, and display it on screen.
For example I should be able to take `<path>T Q`, where `<path>T` cannot change, and `Q` is a variable. It accepts it,however when printing it on screen again the only thing that will appear is `T Q`. I want `<path>T Q` to appear fully.

Other examples of accepted formulae are

```
(B & A)

~A

~(B&A)

<path>T (B & A)
```

etc

My code is something like this

```
  var beginPartBUC      = '^<path>\\(',
  beginPart = '^\(',
  unaryPart         = '(?:~|<path>T)',
  propOrBinaryPart  = '(?:\\w+|\\(.*\\))',
  subwffPart        = unaryPart + '*' + propOrBinaryPart,
  endPart           = '\\)$';

// binary connective regexes

  var conjRegEx = new RegExp(beginPart + '(' + subwffPart + ')&(' + subwffPart + ')' + endPart), // (p&q)
  implRegEx = new RegExp(beginPart + '(' + subwffPart + ')->('  + subwffPart + ')' + endPart), // (p->q)
  equiRegEx = new RegExp(beginPart + '(' + subwffPart + ')<->(' + subwffPart + ')' + endPart); // (p<->q)
 // untilRegEx = new RegExp(beginPartBUC + '(' + subwffPart + ')U('   + subwffPart + ')' + endPart);    //<path>(p U q))
```

Comment: How are you displaying it? If you're putting it in `.innerHTML`, the angle brackets will be treated as HTML tags. You should put it in `.textContent` so it won't be parsed as HTML.

Comment: In SO, put code in backticks so it will be displayed literally, instead of being processed as HTML.

Comment: it gets displayed by calling the method, and appending the parsed formula in html to a div currentFormula
    .html('<strong>Current formula:</strong><br>' + wff.ascii() ) where wff.ascii is the formula. Where would the backtick be put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar pointed out, you're writing to html and `<path>` resembles valid html. You can do this

```
currentFormula.html('<strong>Current formula:</strong><br>' + wff.ascii.replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;"))
```

As an additional note, backticks are used on StackOverflow like this: `sample code` which produces `sample code`. This feature is available in comments as well.

Alternatively, in posts (not comments), you can indent each line with a tab or four spaces (easily done by pressing **`{ }`** in the post editor.

Comment: I see! This is my first time seeing backticks, and in direct HTML i could see how it'd work but It wasn't quite working in my program. This solution worked perfectly, thank you! So what exactly does this replace the > and < with?

Comment: @ZainabUddin `<path>` looks just like HTML. `<path>` doesn't display as text for the same reason `<strong>`, `</strong>`, and `<br>` do not. So we replace `>` with `&gt;`, the proper entity for representing `>` *on* the page, likewise with `<` and `&lt;`.